# Calculate time difference by filtering and combining related entries from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following table

| TicketID | Operator | Datestamp | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | July 20, 2022, 10:30 PM | Changed from State A to B |
| 1 | p1 | July 20, 2022, 11:30 PM | Changed from State B to C |
| 1 | p2 | July 21, 2022, 10:01 PM | Changed from State D to B |
| 1 | p3 | July 21, 2022, 11:41 PM | Changed from State B to A |
| 2 | p1 | November 13, 2022, 11:01 PM | Changed from State C to B |
| 3 | p5 | November 13, 2022, 09:10 AM | Changed from State A to B |
| 3 | p1 | November 13, 2022, 11:10 AM | Changed from State B to C |
| 3 | p1 | November 13, 2022, 11:41 PM | Changed from State C to B |

I need to find out the duration tickets(identified by TicketID) have spent in State B
To clarify further referencing the table above Ticket 1 has spent from July 20, 2022, 10:30 PM to 11:30 PM (1hrs) and July 21, 2022, 10:01 PM to 11:41 PM(1hr40min) in state B making a total of (2hrs40min).

Similarly, Ticket 2 has just one state change to B and there is no entry for a state change from B, hence we assume it is still in State B and the duration becomes CurrentTime-November 13, 2022, 11:01 PM.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to achieve this in a TSQL View. Any help is highly appreciated.
Assuming current time is November 13, 2022, 11:51 PM
The final view output is supposed to be something like below

| TicketID | Duration(in minutes) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 160 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 130 |

Comment: the information about the change should be in 2 columns not in a varchar field

Comment: @nbk Unfortunately the table schema is already in production and can't be changed. Perhaps create an additional view to have the state change info in 2 columns is the way to go but then again the filtering has to be done.

Comment: you can search for `to B` and for `B to`, but search for gaps and island problems, there are some good solutions out there

Comment: what is your desired result

Comment: @RF1991 A view containing TicketID and Time spent in State B(in seconds)

Comment: your 4th row seems to have the wrong date, also can you provide a DDL for the data afaik 12h30 PM is not valid, so show the data with 24 hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the new changed data, it can be done so.

First determinec what is to  and FROM
then, get the `LEAD` of dateime

Finally sum the difference in minutes up

You still should always provide dates as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss`

```
WITH CTE as (SELECT
[TicketID], [Operator], [Datestamp],
CASE WHEN [Remarks] LIKE '%to B%' THen 1
WHEN [Remarks] LIKE '%B to%' THen 2
ELSE 0 END flg
FROM tab1
),
CTE2 AS (SELECT
 [TicketID],flg,[Datestamp], LEAD([Datestamp]) OVER(PARTITION BY [TicketID] ORDER BY [Datestamp] ) date2  
FROM CTE)
SELECT
[TicketID],SUM(ABS(datediff(minute,[Datestamp],COALESCE(date2, getdate())))) as duration
FROM CTE2
WHERE flg = 1
GROUP BY [TicketID]
```

| TicketID | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 160 |
| 2 | 450 |
| 3 | 610 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-8jm_apK)